# Igualar linhas de dois DBGrids

Tags: delphi-xe5, dbgrid

Tenho 2 dbgrids em locais distintos.

Porém, o primeiro DBGrid contém todas as informações (todos os títulos que busquei).
E no segundo DBGrid, contém as informações específicas sobre aquele título (quantidade de parcelas).

DBGrid1:
[image: DBGrid1]

DBGrid2:

[image: DBGrid2]

Segue código para amostra:

```delphi
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.Close;
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Clear;
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('SELECT t707tit.CD_LOTE as lote, t707tit.NR_TIT AS tit, ' +
  't707tit.NR_SEU as numdoc, t707tit.CD_CED as codced, t707tit.vr_jrs_dd as ' +
  'jurosaodia, t707tit.mt_am as multaaomes, t707tit.de_msg_1 as msg1, t707tit.vr_ioc as valorioc, t707tit.vr_abt as valorabat, t707tit.vr_dct as valordesc1, t707tit.vr_dct2 as valordesc2, t707tit.dt_dct as datadesc1, t707tit.dt_dct2 as datadesc2, ' +
  't707tit.de_msg_2 as msg2, t707tit.de_msg_3 as msg3, t707tit.id_pre_ipr as preimpresso, t707tit.DT_PAG as dtpag, t707tit.VR_PAG as valorpago, t707tit.STATUS_canc as status,');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('t707tit.NR_NOS as nossonum, t707tit.DT_EMS ' +
  'as dtemi, t707tit.PZ_PRT as prazopro, t707tit.motivo_canc as motivocanc,');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('t707tit.DT_VEN as dtven, ' +
  't707tit.DV_NR_NOSS as dv, t707tit.cd_ag as codag, t707tit.cd_bco as codbanco, ');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('t707tit.VR_TIT as vltit, ' +
  't707cli.CD_IDT_CLI as codcli, t707tit.id_pre_ipr as preimpresso , t707tit.COD_CDC as codcentrocusto,');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('t707cli.TP_CLI as tipocli, t707cli.NM_CLI ' +
  'as nomecli, ');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('t707cli.CD_CAR as codcart, t707tcar.DE_CAR ' +
  'as descCart');
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.SQL.Add('FROM t707tit, t707cli, t707tcar WHERE ' +
  't707tit.CD_CAR = t707tcar.CD_CAR AND t707cli.CD_CAR = t707tit.CD_CAR AND t707tit.CD_IDT_CLI = ' +
  't707cli.CD_IDT_CLI '+campo+' ORDER BY t707tit.NR_TIT,t707tit.NR_SEU LIMIT '+IntToStr(inicio)+', '+IntToStr(fim));
if maskEmi.Text <> '  /  /  ' then
  begin
    DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.ParamByName('pdataemi').AsDate := StrToDate(maskEmi.Text);
  end;
if maskDataVenc.Text <> '  /  /  ' then
  begin
    DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.ParamByName('pdataven').AsDate := StrToDate(maskDataVenc.Text);
  end;
DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.Open;
```

Código que capta o documento selecionado acima:

```delphi
//selecionando todas as parcelas daquele título
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.Close;
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.SQL.Clear;
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM t707tit WHERE cd_idt_cli = ' +
':pcpfcnpj AND nr_seu like :pnumdoc ORDER BY nr_nos');
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.ParamByname('pcpfcnpj').AsString := DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.FieldByName('codcli').AsString;
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.ParamByname('pnumdoc').AsString := edtNumDoc.Text+'%';
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.Open;
```

A diferença entre 1 e outro, é que lá no primeiro, eu selecionei a parcela 3/4, porem no meu segundo DBGrid, ele continuou na parcela 1/4, como faço para igualhá-las?

Comment: Tens algum código para mostrar? Talvez do `click` da primeira tabela.

Comment: @Earendul, fiz as alterações, o codigo é grande, é apenas uma busca para selecionar o num do documento, e o outro pra captar esse numero e colocar todas as parcelas relacionadas a aquele dbgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o que deu para "pescar" sobre os processos que você executa, pensei no `Locate`.
Execute após o `DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.Open;`.

Exemplo:

```delphi
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.Open;
DMRetaguarda.zqConParcelas.Locate('numdoc', 
    DMRetaguarda.zqConTitulos.FieldByName('numdoc').AsString, []);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo, assim que possível irei testar sim! :D

Comment: Perfeito cara! Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.